# How can I find the C-source definition of function Fcopy_sequence?

Tags: source

How can I find function Fcopy_sequence in the Emacs C source code?

Answer (score 2):

The function `copy-sequence` is written in `C` and is contained within the source code file `fns.c`.  If the source code files are available, they should be in a directory that matches the variable `find-function-C-source-directory` (which can be adjusted as needed).

The decision whether to include source code files is generally made at the time Emacs is built from source, but they can be added in the desired location after Emacs is built and the above-mentioned variable can be adjusted accordingly.

See also the variable `source-directory`.  Keep in mind, however, that the function `find-function-C-source` looks for source code files in the path set by the variable `find-function-C-source-directory` (rather than the variable `source-directory`).

Comment: I'm looking for the definition of C fuction Fcopy_sequence located in the main source code of emacs.

Comment: When a function `DEFUN` is written in `C`, there is a common `DEFUN` name such as `copy-sequence` and also an internal function name `Fcopy_sequence`.  It looks like this:  `DEFUN ("copy-sequence", Fcopy_sequence, Scopy_sequence, 1, 1, 0, doc: /* Return a copy of a list ... */) (Lisp_Object arg) ...`.  It is defined inside the file `.../emacs/src/fns.c` where `emacs` is the root repository.

Comment: Here is a link to the Emacs 28 source code file `fns.c` beginning at line 695:  http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/fns.c?h=emacs-28#n695

Answer (score 0):

In the root of the source tree, run `make tags` to build the various tags files.

Then in Emacs you can use `M-x find-tag` to locate `Fcopy_sequence` using the tags
file in the `src` directory (where all of the C code lives).